# Join existing elements of the DOM to data with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to join existing input text (selected by `d3.selectAll()`) that have unique id's corresponding to keys in the data joined with D3. 
I would like D3 to associate the ids of the input elements to the keys of the data, but it doesn't.

Association is done in the order in witch they appear in the DOM and in the array respectively.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Sample Code:
var inputs = d3.selectAll(".input").data(dt, function (d, i) {return dt[i].key;})

Comment: In what way does the code not work? Do you have a complete minimal example?

Comment: this is very useful for an existing SVG geomap with proper ID on their paths (land)

Answer (score 12):

Remember that the key function will be invoked on each element of your data array (i.e. dt), as well as on each element in your selection (i.e. d3.selectAll(".input")). In both cases, the key function needs to return a valid value and those output values will used to make the association.

To achieve your goal you can do something like the following example. See fiddle for live version: http://jsfiddle.net/2Fkjq/

If your document contains the following:

```
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

​
then executing this:

```
var data = [
    { key: "a", val: "aaa" },
    { key: "b", val: "bbb" },
    { key: "c", val: "ccc" }
];

d3.selectAll("div")
    .data(data, function(d) { return (d && d.key) || d3.select(this).attr("id"); })
    .text(function(d) { return d.val; });
```

will result in this document:

```
<div id="c">ccc</div>
<div id="a">aaa</div>
<div id="b">bbb</div>
```

You see that the key function consists of two parts. The first part is designed for the data array:

```
(d && d.key)
```

That part will return `undefined` for the elements in the d3 selection. The second part targets those elements:

```
d3.select(this).attr("id")
```

Comment: Took me a while to grasp what your data function was really doing. Simplifying it into this made me understand: function(d) { return d ? d.key : this.id; })

Comment: @WouterCoekaerts Thanks for the explanation, I was unable to understand the original one line of code for quite a while too...