# Properly using D3 `data` method with a function and data set passed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

## D3 Tutorial is (partially) broken

It seems to me as if something has changed in D3.

I say this because, as I was trying to understand the data binding **method** better, I looked at [Mike Bostock's selections tutorial page](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/).  This page itself does not work fully (any more), and I'm **sure** it worked fine when he made it!!

Example:

About 3/4 of the way through the page, the following code example is given:

```
var letters = [
  {name: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {name: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {name: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {name: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {name: "E", frequency: .12702}
];

function name(d) {
  return d.name;
}

d3.selectAll("div").data(letters, name);
```

If I run this **exactly within the console of the page itself**, I get the following in the console:

```
Hooray, you opened the JavaScript console. Have fun!
var div = d3.selectAll("div").data(vowels, name);

(index):165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.name (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/:165:11)
    at e (https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:3:13654)
    at Array.Co.data (https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:3:14326)
    at <anonymous>:1:31name @ (index):165e @ d3.v3.min.js:3Co.data @ d3.v3.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ VM3012:1
```

(This is on Max OS X 10.11 and Google Chrome, but that should be irrelevant, because the problem is not machine dependent, as explained below.)

---

## Misunderstanding of the `Data` (Binding) Method

But here's the thing that really confuses me:

- from within Mike's own documentation on this page, as ***I*** understand it, this shouldn't work, anyway.  The `data` method creates basically 2 levels of hierarchy: a single "group", and then a bunch of elements underneath the group.

  - therefore, the method creates 1 group & 5 elements, and the elements contain the data.  Then we attempt to look for attributes in the data, *but at the group level, not the element level*.  Am I understanding this right?
- however, if we simply pass the data, or simply pass a function that interprets data, such as `d3.selectAll("div").data(d3.entries(letters))`, then things work fine again.

So it seems there are clearly 2 things going on:

- my own misunderstanding of this subtlety of how the `data` method works, or how it is supposed to work.
- some changes within d3 itself such that this tutorial can no longer function as it originally did.

This is still all using V3 of D3, as the source code in that page itself says:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was going to close this as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577368/d3-js-key-function-running-twice-on-simple-selector-array-combo) but I think it requires a little more explanation.**

In short, this is the expected behavior.  You essentially have existing divs with **no data** bound to them.  The key function attempts to execute on them, `d` is undefined and you get your `uncaught typerror`.  Here's the simplified version:

```js
var letters = [
  {name: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {name: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {name: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {name: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {name: "E", frequency: .12702}
];

function name(d) {
  return d.name;
}

d3.selectAll("div").data(letters, name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**BUT WAIT** that means the tutorial is horribly broken, right?

No, you see this because you are executing it *out-of-order*.  The previous step has you data-bind to those div's without a `key` function.  Then when you re-bind with a `key` function, there's existing data on those divs (`d` is defined) and your problem goes away:

```js
var numbers = [4, 5, 18, 23, 42];
      
var letters = [
  {name: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {name: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {name: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {name: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {name: "E", frequency: .12702}
];

function name(d) {
  return d.name;
}

d3.selectAll("div").data(numbers);

d3.selectAll("div").data(letters, name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**BUT WAIT** this sucks and shouldn't `d3` handle this for me?

No, because in real-life `d3` usage, you'll never see really see this. You won't have pre-existing `<div>` lying around to data-bind to.  Instead, you'll be using `d3` to manage the full life-time of those `<div>`s (the full enter, exit, update cycle).  In short, those divs will always be data-bound otherwise you'd never need them.

```js
      var letters = [
        {name: "A", frequency: .08167},
        {name: "B", frequency: .01492},
        {name: "C", frequency: .02780},
        {name: "D", frequency: .04253},
        {name: "E", frequency: .12702}
      ];
      
      function name(d) {
        return d.name;
      }

      d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(letters, name)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .html(function(d){ return d.name });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mark, for the excellent answer, and for not closing this as a duplicate!  While it is similar, it's also really tricky to understand how these steps work "under the hood", so it's sometimes hard to even see how similar problems really are.