# How can I bind data.key --> element.id on existing markup in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an existing `<svg>` and I have defined groups `<g>` where each group has its own unique id.

```
<g id="id_1"><text>...</text></g>
<g id="id_2"><text>...</text></g>
<g id="id_3"><text>...</text></g>
<g id="id_4"><text>...</text></g>
```

Similarly I have data formatted as

```
data = { "id_2" : { "name" : value1, "description" : value2, ... }, 
         "id_4" : { "name" : value1, "description" : value2, ... }, 
         "id_9" : { "name" : value1, "description" : value2, ... } };
```

for each row. Notice that not all id's match!

I do not wish to replace the `<g>`, instead I would like to bind each data row to the correct `<g>` tag where the id's match. The default behavior of `d3.select('g').data(d3.values(data))` does not support this as it will bind by index. How can I do this?

I have sample code at jsbin with indexed data binding that you can modify.

http://jsbin.com/qifale/1/edit

Comment: Try `d3.entries(data)` instead of `d3.values(data)` since you lose any id information when `d3.values` is called.

Comment: Also, what is the `.bind` function. I cannot find it anywhere it d3 docs?

Comment: Sorry, that should be data and not bind. Changed it on my Q to avoid confusion. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149145/join-existing-elements-of-the-dom-to-data-with-d3-js

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That works, amazingly! But the solution makes no sense to me, if you want to formulate an answer that includes an explanation I will give you credit for the answer.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I get it now! The main thing to realize is that the key function is executed twice, one time to return a key for each html element and a second time to return a key for each data record. The first time around you return id from html element and second time around you return key or name etc from your data record!

Comment: @sunefred Yep. Does the other answer solve your problem? If so I'd close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the remove command. Add `nodesUpdate.exit().remove();` to remove the unmapped svg elements. You will also need to change `.data(d3.values)` to `.data(d3.entries)` to ensure the keys match up.

```js
var data = {
  "id_2": {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Description": "A common fella"
  },
  "id_4": {
    "Name": "Ann Lady",
    "Description": "Has long hair"
  },
  "id_8": {
    "Name": "Luke Force",
    "Description": "Green Lightsaber"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  bind(data);
});

function bind(data) {

  // get svg element
  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  // select and bind data by index
  nodesUpdate = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.entries(data));

  // update the data
  nodesUpdate
    .select("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value.Name + " : " + d.value.Description;
    });

  nodesUpdate.exit().remove();

  // What I really want though is to match the data such that data[id_2] is matched
  // to <g class="id_2"> and so on. Nodes 1 and 3 should not be included in the update set!
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="">
  <g id="id_1" transform="translate(20, 30)">
    <text>-- 1 --</text>
  </g>
  <g id="id_2" transform="translate(20, 60)">
    <text>-- 2 --</text>
  </g>
  <g id="id_3" transform="translate(20, 90)">
    <text>-- 3 --</text>
  </g>
  <g id="id_4" transform="translate(20, 120)">
    <text>-- 4 --</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but you are missing the whole point of my question. My problem is to bind key -> id and not bind by index. The output would then me

[-- 1 --]  
[John Doe : A common fella]  
[-- 3 --]  
[Ann Lady : Has long hair]  

Each row in the data bound to the g element with the correct id, then only thoose are updated. The other elements are not removed and not changed.

Comment: @sunefred Are you trying to mix elements in the same svg, where some are bound to d3 and some are not? And then sort both elements together?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by sort elements together. But let me explain my particular problem. I have a flowchart with a bunch of sensors describing an industrial process. Each sensor has an id and is placed by hand in the correct position in the flowchart. Data is retrieved from the server, but sometimes data might be missing or be in a strange order. What I do know is that the data for each sensor includes the id that I have used when drawing the svg. So, I only want to update those sensors that has data coming from the server i.e. with matching id's.

Comment: So the initial data is not drawn using d3.js, correct? If so, then would be be easier to just use jQuery to update the text nodes and add new ones?