# D3. Is it possible to connect SVG and JSON

Tags: json, d3.js, svg

Before embarking on this task...I wanted to ask the following question about connecting a graphics based object defined using SVG and some data which is presented in json format.

This following is a greatly simplified example of what I am trying to do.  Firstly, here is a snippet of the SVG data (I know D3 could generate this):

```
<rect id = "A" x="21.8" y="31.9" width="60.2" height="44.6"/>
<rect id = "B" x="133.3" y="49.4"  width="60.2" height="44.6"/>
<rect id = "C" x="61.8" y="104.7" width="60.2" height="44.6"/>
```

And now here is a snippet of JSON data:

```
{
    "A": "This is A",
    "B": "And now B",
    "C": "Finally C"
}
```

What I would like to do is when the user hovers over rectangle A (the first SVG element with id = "A" then the application would respond by printing a message on screen defined in the JSON file (i.e. "This is A").

I have tried to simplify my actual problem by including very simple examples.  But the essence of my problem is how to get D3 to "join" the two data sets.

Thanks,

Comment: Actually that is more or less the whole point of d3.js: It connects HTML or SVG artifacts with some dataset, so that one can always retrieve the data, that is associated with a specific artifact.

Comment: Okay great.  Can D3 connect SVG.. though..?

Comment: @markthekoala Would you like to bind JSON data to existing SVG elements or do you generate SVG elements with d3.js?

Comment: @user3714582 thanks for responding.  I don't want D3 to generate the SVG...this is because they are rather complex graphics that are best generated using Inkscape / Illustrator rather than with code. But the JSON data is a machine generated file (a dump from a db table actually).

Comment: It sounds like you don't need D3 at all for what you want to do.  D3 is used to generate various types of graphs in SVG form.  What you descibed could be done with, for example, jQuery, or even vanilla JS.

Comment: @markthekoala as Paul LeBeau wrote if you would like to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ggotn1qv/ there is no need to use d3.js. There are just selections and events which could also be done with e.g. jQuery.

Comment: You are better off showing us the complicated example and we can judge better from knowing exactly what you want to do if D3 is appropriate.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149145/join-existing-elements-of-the-dom-to-data-with-d3-js