# d3: how to link data to an element manually

Tags: d3.js

I have 5 existing `div` elements and an array `data` of 5 values. 
Currently `d` in d3 `each` returns `undefined` while `data[i]` return it value.

```
d3.selectAll("div")                
                .each(function(d,i){                                
                    console.log(d, i, data[i]);
}
```

How to associate `div` and `data[i]` so that `d` will return the value of `data[i]` without using d3 `enter()`?

Comment: If there is no bound data, passing `d` into your each function will yield nothing.

Comment: ... `i` should still be the index of the `selectAll('div').each()`, so you can use this value to access the `data` array. However, these are not bound. So if your data array changes, it may no longer match your array of divs.

Comment: your solution is working but i'd like to learn the bound.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149145/join-existing-elements-of-the-dom-to-data-with-d3-js?rq=1). Add `id` to each `div` and then use join to `data` via `id` and `key`.

```
data = [
            {"key":"0","val":"10"},
            {"key":"1","val":"5"},
            {"key":"2","val":"8"}
        ];    
...
d3.selectAll("div.h-bar")
                .data(data, function(d:any){
                    var x = d? d.key : this.id;
                    return x;
                })                
                .each(function(d:any,i:any){         
                    console.log(d, i, data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `datum(newvalue)` to assign the `newvalue` to each element's model.

```
data                            
                .forEach(function(d:any){         
                    var item = d3.select('#div'+d.key).datum(d);
                });
```