# D3 key function param undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I would bind data with elements

First I select my elements

```
let trainSelect = svg.selectAll('.train-w-dir');
```

When I `console.log(trainSelect)` I get elements not emty

Then I bind data

```
trainSelect
        .data(schedules, function(d: ISchedule) {
          return d.train;
        })
        .enter()
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

I check schedules on the debugger it contains array of objects.
But inside the key function `d` id `undefined` I don't get why ?

So I get error `Cannot read property 'train' of undefined`

Comment: You're renaming `d` to `ISchedule` so you should do `return ISchedule.train;`

Comment: I'm defining it's type because without `ISchedule` I get TS error `Property 'train' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

Comment: Oh, so you're using TS, the tag wasn't there before so it was a misleading

Answer (score 2):

The key function is evaluated **twice**: once per each element of the selection and once per each datum. In the words of the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) (emphasis mine):

> This key function is **evaluated for each selected element**, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (*nodes*[*i*]); the returned string is the element’s key. The key function is then **also evaluated for each new datum in data**, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the group’s new data, with this as the group’s parent DOM element; the returned string is the datum’s key.

In the first run when evaluated for each selected element `d` will be undefined if you have not yet bound data to the elements.

It is not clear from the code you provided what might be the best solution to your problem. You could either provide a safe-guard against undefined values in the key function or, probably better, rebuild the way you bind data to your elements.

Related: [*Join existing elements of the DOM to data with d3.js*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149145/join-existing-elements-of-the-dom-to-data-with-d3-js)

Comment: I missed this answer of yours. It always bothered me that the API is like you quoted, I reckon it should be: *"This key function is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the **element's** datum (d)..."*, instead of *"current"*, which makes us think that it refers to the data's datum, not the element's datum.