# Show tooltip on hover using d3-tip.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I would like to show tooltip on hovering existing svg elements.

In the [live example](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) the elements to hover are created when binding data. In my case these elements exists already in DOM (circles). so I need to select them right after `selectedElms.enter()`

My question is how can I apply `tip.show` and `tip.hide` on circles ?

```js
var data = [{
    train: 1
}, {
    train: 2
}, {
    train: 3
}, {
    train: 4
}]
var svg = d3.select('svg')
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.train + "</span>";
    })

svg.call(tip);

let selectedElms = d3.selectAll('circle').data(data, function(d) {
    if (d != undefined) {
        return d.train
    }
})
console.log('hi')
selectedElms.enter().on('mouseover', tip.show).on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"
></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<svg height="400" width="500">
  <circle data='1' cx="100" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="1"  />
  <circle data='2' cx="200" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="2" />
  <circle data='3' cx="300" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="3"  />
  <circle data='4' cx="400" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="4"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: @RachelGallen Alright, then let's clean up these comments.

Comment: @infodev You have to versions of included two versions of D3 in your snippet with the latter winning over the former. Your version of d3-tip doesn't seem to work with d3 **v4**. This may just be a copy-and-past error while creating the demo, though. Note, that I ditch v4 in favor of v3 in my answer. You may have to correct for that in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just two things to correct to make it work as expected:

1. Like I mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271604/4235784) to your first [question](http:///questions/58270789) on this topic, the key function is executed twice while matching data to DOM elements. To bind data to existing DOM elements you have to use the technique as laid out in [*Join existing elements of the DOM to data with d3.js*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149145/join-existing-elements-of-the-dom-to-data-with-d3-js). In your case the key function becomes

   ```
   .data(data, function(d) {
     return (d && d.train) || this.id;
   })
   ```

   The first expression `d && d.train` checks if `d` refers to an actual value and, if true, evalutates to its property `.train`. This is the case while the key function is executed for each datum in the `data` argument. The second expression `this.id` is conditionally evaluated if `d` is `undefined` which is the case while the key function is executed for the selected, i.e. already existing, elements. If a match is found the respective datum is bound to the element.
2. You are only interested in updating elements which already exist in the DOM. For that reason you do not need to use the enter selection at all. The update selection which is returned by `.data()` will suffice. You can just drop the call to `.enter()`.

Have a look at the following snippet to see it in action:

```js
var data = [{
    train: 1
}, {
    train: 2
}, {
    train: 3
}, {
    train: 4
}]
var svg = d3.select('svg')
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.train + "</span>";
    })

svg.call(tip);

let selectedElms = d3.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return (d && d.train) || this.id;
  })

selectedElms
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<svg height="400" width="500">
  <circle data='1' cx="100" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="1"  />
  <circle data='2' cx="200" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="2" />
  <circle data='3' cx="300" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="3"  />
  <circle data='4' cx="400" cy="110" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="4"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: I have a problem when I implement the solution on my real app. `this.id` does not exist ( Im using Angular )  `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Window'`